# Richfaces dataTable works fine, but ExtendedDataTable is not showing data

Tags: datatable, richfaces

We are using Richfaces 4.1.0, and I am trying to use an extendedDataTable.  I started (for simplicity's sake) with dataTable.  The code below works fine, and shows my data in a table, as expected.

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{recipientBean.recipientList}" var="recipient" selectionMode="none" id="recipientTable">
    <rich:column sortable="false" id="col_1" label="Name">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Name" id="name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{recipient.name}" id="rec_name" />
    </rich:column>
    <!-- More columns below, removed for post brevity -->
</rich:dataTable>
```

We are expecting a large number of records, so we would like the table to be scrollable.  I thought that I could just change the dataTable to extendedDataTable, however, when I do that, no data shows up at all.

I just started to inspect the element in Chrome, and all of a sudden the data showed up.  So when I inspect the element, I see the values in the html, but they don't display when the page loads.

Could this be a style issue? An attribute that is missing (something that is needed for extendedDataTable, but not needed for dataTable)?

What else am I missing?

EDIT:  I do have this extendedDataTable inside a rich:tabPanel.  When I remove the rich:tabPanel it displays correctly (but I really need the tabPanel).  Is this a known issue?

EDIT2:  It does display correctly if it is on the first tab of the rich:tabPanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a bug report on the joss site.  The work around was to use the switch type of Ajax instead of client for the tab panel.

Comment: Hi Innova. Can you provide the url to the bug report you've found? Thank you. Zubi

Comment: I just ran on this issue too... setting switch type to ajax didn't help.

Comment: did you fix the problem? i still encounter it in RF 4.3.4 and IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

If it still doesn't work after switching to `ajax` switchType you may try to use redirect instead of forward, when you navigate to the page with rich:extendedDataTable. To achieve this you may e.g. add `?redirect-faces=true` to the page URL.